# What percent of the Roman Republic's population were citizens in various centuries?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-republic

Does anyone have any sources mentioning the percentages of citizens at various times, or the populations of citizens and corresponding total populations so I can calculate percents? I looked at dozens of sources online without finding this kind of information.

Comment: I dont think there are percentages available. But a key date for you is the year 212AD when the _Constitutio Antoniniana_  was issued giving all free men in the Roman empire citizenship regardless of ethnic origins

Comment: Surely someone's done some estimation of such numbers in the last 2000 years.

Comment: How many censuses were taken for the Roman republic during its history? Censuses conducted every 10 years or so, has only been a practice in some developed countries for aprox the past 200 years

Comment: @Fred Censuses were regularly taken in ancient rome, although they were obviously not as reliable as they are today, and their purpose gradually shifted over time.

Comment: @bt:Yes; their original (primary) use was to determine the size and availability of the citizen militia in the four categories: Velites, Hastati, Principes, and Triari.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Alright, another point is official censuses are not the only sources of population and demographic estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two estimations about the number of *slaves* for the 2nd and 1st centuries BC.

- P. Brunt [1] estimates there were 3 000 000 slaves in a total population of 7 500 000 people.
- J.C. Dumont [2] estimates that *at least* 32% of the population was in slavery.

From these numbers, we deduce that roughly 60% of the population were free.
Halve this proportion to exclude women, further exclude children, and the proportion drops to 20-25% of **free men** (I have no precise idea for the proportion of children).
Not all of them were citizens, but at least we have an upper bound.

[1]: Italian Manpower, 225 BC -- AD 14, Oxford, 1971

[2]: Servus. Rome et l'esclavage sous la République, Rome - Paris, 1987

Comment: Was there not a significant number of non-citizen freedmen at that time?

Comment: @BT My bad, edited. However, all free men in Italy are given the citizenship in 89 BC. Furthermore, a freedman has the right to vote, but not the right to be elected. The children of a freedman are citizens. So I would say that the proportion of non-citizen freedmen is reasonably low.

Comment: Ah i see, alright, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!